# How can I add column to database after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

Ok this might be very simple and stupid question.

I deployed an app to a nginx server using Passenger/Capistrano but now I need to add a column to the database.

My plan was to do it on my Computer and then deploy again to the server...

I've a very nice deploy setup that I don't want to mess with

but when I add the line `rails g migration AddStockQuantityToProduct`to create the migration Rails throws back this error:

```
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are  versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

 bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
 rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
 git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

 WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  rails-html-sanitizer (>= 1.0.2, ~> 1.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
 WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
 Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

What can I do to create this migration with out damaging my setup for deploy?
I'm afraid to mix up my deploy setup if I use some of this:

```
Here's how to upgrade:

 bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
 rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
 git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
```

Comment: If you're using version control you shouldn't have any concerns here, you can roll-back any changes you make. If not, that's the first thing to look at getting.

Comment: I'm using git....so it should be ok